# applying for a position below your level

Tags: professionalism, applications

I recently came across a listing for a junior position at a company that i would like to work for. i am presently at what most would consider the mid to full professional level of my career.

would it be inappropriate to apply, hoping that with my experience i would be considered for employment at the higher level? i was either going to simply apply, or, contact the company directly and ask if they would consider a more experienced person.

Answer (score 2):

Inappropriate? No.  But keep in mind if they were looking for a mid/senior level person, that would be what the listing was for.

You can ask to be considered for a more senior level, but if they don't have that kind of opening available, you probably won't get very far

Answer (score 0):

A company usually thinks of its employees like "progressing". Therefore wanting to stay in the same position is already kind of strange and sometimes not well perceived.

Even more weird can be the will to step down, so the crucial point here is how you motivate the question which you will get: with your experience, why are you applying for a junior position?

If you are able to tell a convincing story there would be no big issues.

Comment: The most compelling would probably be if your primary skills are in some obsolete technology and you want to learn a more useful modern technology you haven't used before. A junior position would be the perfect platform for that. And with previous general experience, you would learn fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not professionally inappropriate, but it might be inappropriate to yourself.

You might not have any opportunity to advance at this new job, so it's unfair to yourself to assume you can finagle something comparable to what you have now. It's also slightly unreasonable to expect them to accommodate your hopes instead of filling the position for as little cost to the company as possible (their goal).

If you can live with the job listed, then go for it. I would not "call ahead" to ask if you're "too good" for the job, as that tips your hand to them about the ulterior motive. It would be best just to wow them and nail the interview. Talk about needing a change of pace, or how much you just love their brand to overcome reservations about over-qualification.

If you do a great job you can usually move up in most workplaces, but if they get a sniff of that as a near-contingency, that could prompt a search team member to start a discussion among themselves about those doubts after your interview, and that conversation never goes your way...